# Make an Image Full Screen

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-registry, visual-basic

I have a bunch of TVs that are used for digital signage powered by intel nucs running windows 10.  I am currently using a Visual Basic Script that works okay but was wondering if there is a better way to do this through the system.  The image needs to go into a fullscreen mode so that it will work as a sign essentially.  Could this be done with a PowerShell script or possibly though the registry to make photos or paint always open in full screen?  Any ideas welcomed.

Here is the Visual Basic code that I am using now:

```
strFileName = "FILE PATH OF IMAGE"
Dim objshell : Set objshell=createobject("wscript.shell")

objshell.run "mspaint " & strFileName

wscript.sleep 1000
objshell.AppActivate("NAME_OF_IMAGE - Paint")
wscript.sleep 1000
objshell.SendKeys "{F11}"
wscript.sleep 1000
objshell.SendKeys "{F11}"
wscript.sleep 1000
objshell.SendKeys "{F11}"
```

Comment: you can `Start-Process "c:\pics\pic1.jpg" -WindowStyle maximized` and this will auto open the image in the default app for viewing images, which can be changed in control panel (powershell)

Comment: maybe an open source software may solve your problem. https://www.softwaresuggest.com/blog/best-free-open-source-digital-signage-software/

Comment: Narzard that works however it does not fullscreen the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for 3rdP software, as suggested by arthur kamande.

Nothing stops you from using SendKeys with PowerShell. Just convert the VBS to PowerShell code, as it's virtually the same.

Example Powershell using SendKeys.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic") 

Start-Process -FilePath 'notepad.exe'

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Untitled - Notepad")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%(fs)")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{F4}")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("x")
```